# PIG Data Processing

Tags: apache-pig, bigdata

I have the below requirement Please Help me how can I process it using apache pig ?

**INPUT :**

```
**

SYSTEM IP : 1.1.1.1

KERNEL : CENT OS

UP TIME : 0.00 , 0.00

**
```

SYSTEM IP : 2.2.2.2

KERNEL : CENT OS

UP TIME : 0.00 , 0.00

**Expected Output :**

```
SYSTEM IP : 1.1.1.1|KERNEL : CENT OS|UP TIME : 0.00 , 0.00

SYSTEM IP : 2.2.2.2|KERNEL : CENT OS|UP TIME : 0.00 , 0.00
```

Comment: is " ** " part of your input file or is it something that you have used to distinguish two sets.

Comment: For distinguishing two sets

Comment: How do you plan to distinguish them while processing the input file ?

Comment: Each set of record is starting with ** , so If I can check from one ** to another ** and take the set and make it one line using pipe separator and in that loop I will do the same for another set but the thing is I'm unable to implement this cause it is just couple of days I learned Pig .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input I think we could tackle this by writing 
a custom Loader which reads the input file with ** as record delimiter. So when you have a record in a Pig relation it represents whatever content you have between "**".

Comment: That I'm unable to write . Can you please share the code ? and also I want to make the record which is in between the "**" .

Comment: I do not have the code for doing this. :-| , I think you will have to spend some time reading the documentation and figuring out how to write the custom loader.

Comment: Ok . I will try .

Comment: Ok I used group by all and I have following output
(all,{(Distro info:CentOS release 6.5 (Final)),(SYSTEM IP:1.1.1.1 ),(),(**),(Distro info:CentOS release 6.5 (Final)),(SYSTEM IP:2.2.2.2 ),(),(**)})

so how can I split using ** and make each record in a new line ?

Comment: IMHO, creating record is a responsibility of a loader function. The code that you would end up writing ( may be a UDF that processes group of tuples) may be similar to loader. It may be helpful for you if you figure that out instead of doing groupby and processing it. Another option to shy away from Loader is to process the input using a shell script to merge lines between *** into one.

Comment: Ok I got that part . Did you connect aws elasticsearch with apache pig ?